# merge one ore more arrays with alternate order

Tags: arrays, sorting

is there any possibility to merge one ore more arrays with alternate order?
For instance:

```
$array1 = array(red,green,blue);
$array2 = array(brown,yellow,pink);
$array3 = array(black,white,orange);
```

needed result:

```
array(
 0 => red,
 1 => brown,
 2 => black,
 3 => green,
 4 => yellow,
 5 => white,
 6 => blue,
 7 => pink,
 8 => orange);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a loop as follows (pseudo-code):

```
continue = true ;
index    = 0    ;
while continue {
    continue = false ;
    if (array1[index] <> null) {
       big_array.push(array1[index]) ;
       continue = true ;
    }
    if (array2[index] <> null) {
       big_array.push(array2[index]) ;
       continue = true ;
    }
    if (array3[index] <> null) {
       big_array.push(array3[index]) ;
       continue = true ;
    }
}
```

This code will also take care situations when the length of the arrays are not equal.